# what's the better idea when accessing to base form's control from derived form

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't know how should I access to ase form's control.

1. Set Control's access modifier as 'Protected'.

   ```
   public class BaseForm
   {
       protected System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
       protected System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
   }

   public class Form2 : BaseForm
   {
       public Form2()
       {
           button1.Text = "J. Doe";
           label1.Text = "Kim";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Remain Control as private and create Property

   ```
   public class BaseForm
   {
       private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
       private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;

       public Button Button1
       {
           get { return button1; }
       }
       public Label Lable1
       {
           get { return label1; }
       }

   }

   public class Form2 : BaseForm
   {
       public Form2()
       {
           Button1.Text = "J. Doe";
           Lable1.Text = "Kim";
       }
   }
   ```

which is the better idea?

Comment: Neither are good ideas :)

Comment: @Aybe So.. what's good idea?

Comment: A good idea would be to not expose UI elements at all, rather `Name`-like properties; but then comes the concept of data binding against model and so on ... I'd suggest to get started with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding

Comment: @Aybe Thanks. I'll check it out.

Comment: If you are always going to extend a class to BaseForm, use proteted, in case you want to call the variables from anywhere, use the access descriptors (get; set;)

Answer (score 1):

Protected tells VS that the elements can only be accessed by the child classes of the class where they were declared

```
public class BaseForm
{

    //All BaseForm child classes will have access to the protected elements
    protected System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    protected System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
}

public class Form2 : BaseForm
{
    public Form2()
    {
        button1.Text = "J. Doe";
        label1.Text = "Kim";
    }
}
```

In your code, BaseForm is a parent class, so inheriting the methods of the parent class is the best option.

```
public class BaseForm
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;

    public Button Button1
    {
        get { return button1; }
    }
    public Label Lable1
    {
        get { return label1; }
    }

}

public class Form2 : BaseForm
{
    public Form2()
    {
        Button1.Text = "J. Doe";
        Lable1.Text = "Kim";
    }
}
```

Here, accessors are used, which are generally used to pass parameters to global variables that revalue values ​​of local variables and that are used to pass parameters between two independent classes

If you are always going to extend a class to BaseForm, use proteted, in case you want to call the variables from anywhere, use the access descriptors (get; set;)